# HDF5 attributes written in C++ are always arrays in python

Tags: c++, hdf5, h5py

I am exporting some attributes for an HDF5 file using the C++ API. To simplify some stuff, I have created a `writeAttribute` function like this:

```
template <typename AttributeT>
void writeAttribute(const std::string &attrName, const AttributeT &attrValue, H5::Group &group)
{
    std::array<hsize_t, 1> attributeDataSpace{1};
    auto attributeType = H5AttributeType<AttributeT>::predType();
    auto frameAttribute = group.createAttribute(attrName, attributeType, H5::DataSpace{1, attributeDataSpace.data()});
    frameAttribute.write(attributeType, reinterpret_cast<const void *>(&attrValue));
}
```

The `AttributeT` is just used to set the size of the datatype

If I now import a file created using this functions with h5py in python, the attributes are always stored in a numpy array of size 1. This is weird, I would have expected to values be stored directly as numbers.

Is this common or am I doing something wrong in the export?

Comment: When I write a scalar to an attribute with `h5py`, the reloaded value is `numpy scalar`, e.g. `np.float64` or `np.int64`.  That's half way between a python scalar and a 0d numpy array.  I don't know what the C++ is doing.

Answer (score 0):

A scalar attribute uses an empty DataSpace, not one of size 1.

```
H5::DataSpace attrspace;
H5::Attribute attr = parent.createAttribute(name, attributeType, attrspace);
attr.write(attributeType, &value);
```